# What is the most suitable way to get the boundary of a state or a country or the whole world dynamically?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, geojson, administrative-boundaries

I am working on a project where I have to create filled map charts based on the data client has provided. The data has latitude and longitude information. Based on the selected level (city or state or country) I have to get the boundary shapes of those locations and then filled them with appropriate color.

I have tried nominatim framework api. They are giving response in geoJson format which I am rendering in client side using leaftlet.js. As for a single country the size of geoJson is around 1-1.5 MB, I cannot use this approach.

I tried searching for any api service which can serve boundary data in geoJSON but still no luck. I have seen people suggesting to download and store shapefile(shp, shx), and convert them to geoJSON using QGIS manually. But as I am going to use it for a web-application and need to get/generate shapefiles on request from client, I don't know how this kind of approach will fit in it. 
Suggest me some tools and libraries which can be used to convert this data to a supported format for a web application.

I know some of the things is sounding naive, as I am very new to this field. Let me know if you need any clarity on anything I said about my project.

Please help me to find a better approach to solve this use-case.

Comment: why do you want to create the boundary data dynamically? The political boundaries don't change that often. It might slow your web application down if you have to create the boundaries on the fly each time.

Comment: Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DcEMC7?p=preview) if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @ChrisP Can you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: @JonatasWalker The code is working as expected, but it is quite slow for Africa. Is there any way to improve the speed?

Comment: My first idea was to create the boundary data manually. QGIS as you mentioned is a tool you could use for that. However I do not know how many different areas with boundary data you need to provide. I would then try to edit the column that serves the fill of the shape dynamically in my web service. Check out the java script library http://d3js.org/ they have some map examples and try to find out how they do it.

Comment: @ChrisP even with d3.js we need to provide geojson information for boundaries. I am not able to find any online service which provide boundary information in geojson or a easy approach to setup a local server of boundary information which will be sent to client on demand.

Comment: Hello Ankit, are you looking for a web service like that one from OSM user Wambacher via https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/ ? ... There you can select and download boundaries based on OpenStreetMap data (pay attentioin to its open licence) in different formats.